# select anidados en c# ajax mvc y bootstrap-select

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

resulta que estoy cargando un select con los datos obtenidos de una base de datos con ajax, este es el codigo c#

para ello utilizo bootstrap-select

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

codigo de la vista

```
 <div id="buttonGrp" class="form-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="searchConditionsPanel">
                <div class="panel-body mysearchpanel">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label" for="Procedimiento">Procedimiento</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @*<input type="text" id="maxPrice" name="maxPrice" class="form-control input-normal" placeholder="Procedimiento">*@
                            <select id="IdProcedimiento" name="IdProcedimiento" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">                                   
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label" for="Licitante">Licitante</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @*<input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" class="form-control input-normal" placeholder="Razon Social">*@
                            <select id="IdProveedor" name="IdProveedor" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;SEARCH &nbsp;" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">                           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


  public JsonResult GetCatalogoProcedimientos()
    {

        var query = from mp in db.MtoProcedimientos
                    select new
                    {
                        MtoProcedimientoId = mp.MtoProcedimientoId,
                        NoLicitacion = mp.NoLicitacion
                    };

        return new JsonResult { Data = query.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

aquí el ajax con el que cargo el primer select

```
function GetCatalogoProcedimientos(element) {     
if(element != null){
    //element.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">Loading.....</option>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url:  _urlBase + "Procedimientos/GetCatalogoProcedimientos",
        data: "{}",   
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
               element.append('<option value="'
                    + data.MtoProcedimientoId + '">'
                    + data.NoLicitacion + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            $("#dvAlerta > span").text("Error al llenar el combo");
        }
    });
}}
```

bien ahora quiero que cuando seleccione un elemento del primer select se cargue el segundo select  para lo cual utilizo el siguiente action result.

```
 public JsonResult GetProveedoresConOferta(int id)
    {

        var Result = (from MO in db.MtoOfertas
                     join MP in db.MtoProveedores on MO.MtoProveedorId equals MP.MtoProveedorId
                      where MO.MtoProcedimientoId == id
                      select new {
                         //MO.MtoProcedimientoId,
                         MO.MtoProveedorId,
                         MP.RazonSocial
                     }).OrderBy(o => o.RazonSocial).Distinct();


        return new JsonResult { Data = Result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

y el ajax es el siguiente.

```
function GetProveedoresConOferta(id) {
if (id!=0) {               
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: _urlBase + "Ofertas/GetProveedoresConOferta",
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Data) {
            console.log(Data);
            $('#IdProveedor').css("disabled",true);
            $.each(Data, function (i, Data) {
                $('#IdProveedor').append('<option value="'
                     + Data.MtoProveedorId + '">'
                     + Data.RazonSocial + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            $("#dvAlerta > span").text("Error al llenar el combo");
        }
    });
}    }
```

este se dispara cuando en el select selecciono un registro con el siguiente codigo.

```
 $('#IdProcedimiento').on('hidden.bs.select', function (e) {      
    var item = $('#IdProcedimiento').val();
    if (item != 0)
    {            
        GetProveedoresConOferta(item);
    }
});
```

el problema radica en que aunque el resultado de ajax me retorna registros no me es posible cargarlos en el segundo select.

podrían echarme apoyarme para encontrar la solución, muchas gracias

el valor devuelto es un array de tipo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo curioso es que si al select con id **"IdProveedor"** le quito la clase **selectpicker**, si carga la información.

gracias

```
[…]
```

0: Object { MtoProveedorId: 100, RazonSocial: "DIAGNODISTRIBUTIONS, S.A. DE C.V." }
1: Object { MtoProveedorId: 103, RazonSocial: "DIAGNOQUIM, S. A. DE C.V." }
2: Object { MtoProveedorId: 181, RazonSocial: "GENESIS HEALTHCARE ADVISERS, S. A. DE C. V." }
3: Object { MtoProveedorId: 245, RazonSocial: "KABLA COMERCIAL, S.A. DE C.V." }
4: Object { MtoProveedorId: 304, RazonSocial: "MEXGLOBAL, S.A. DE C.V." }
5: Object { MtoProveedorId: 323, RazonSocial: "PASTEUR HEALTH CARE S.A. DE C.V." }
6: Object { MtoProveedorId: 329, RazonSocial: "PHARMACUR, S.A. DE C.V" }
7: Object { MtoProveedorId: 435, RazonSocial: "AXMILAB, S.A. DE C.V." }
8: Object { MtoProveedorId: 437, RazonSocial: "BIOXINTEGRAL SERVICIOS, S.A. DE C.V." }
9: Object { MtoProveedorId: 439, RazonSocial: "CINVESTILAB, S.A. DE C.V." }
10: Object { MtoProveedorId: 441, RazonSocial: "CONSUMIBLES DC, S.A. DE C.V." }
11: Object { MtoProveedorId: 443, RazonSocial: "DISTRIBUIDORA DE EQUIPO MÉDICO, S.A. DE C.V." }
12: Object { MtoProveedorId: 444, RazonSocial: "MULTIEQUIPOS Y MEDICAMENTOS, S.A. DE C.V." }
length: 13
**proto**: Array []

Comment: Podrías indicarnos en el `$.each` que valor recuperas en `Data` antes de realizar el `append`.

Comment: @Horacio la idea es agregar todo como texto. Una imagen puede facilitar una descripción, pero no ayuda a ver el resultado. Si alguien quiere probar tu código, no lo hagas reescribir todo el resultado, facilitá la tarea poniéndolo como texto. Además, pensemos en quienes están en un dispositivo con pantalla chica o tienen problemas de vista,

Comment: ok,  enterado no volveré a poner imágenes en las siguientes publicaciones aquí va el texto del resultado;

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Filtrar un DropDownList desde otro DropDownList](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21472/filtrar-un-dropdownlist-desde-otro-dropdownlist)