# ¿Cómo obtener el item seleccionado de un dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, mvc

Tengo 3 dropdownlist, uno lo lleno desde el controlador (ya lo logré llenar) pero quiero que en cuanto seleccione un valor del primer dropdown se use ese valor para una consulta y llenar el segundo dropdown, y del segundo, el tercero.

Cómo podría llenarlo desde el controlador o la lista?

He visto que podría llenarlo desde la vista así:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Modelo, dbTablaParallenar.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }))
```

pero cómo podría filtrar lo que tiene dbTablaParallenar?

o como segunda opción, así lleno el primer dropdownlist:

```
var tabla1= from ee in contextoBd.dbTabla1
            select ee.Id;

var tabla2= (from u in contextoBd.dbTabla2
            where dbTabla2.Contains(u.Id)
            select new
            {
                        u.Id,
                        u.Descripcion
            }).ToList();

Tabla2.Add(new { Id= "00", Descripcion = "-- Seleccione -- " });

var lista= new SelectList(Tabla2.OrderBy(o => o.Id), "Id", "Descripcion");

ViewData["Lista"] = lista;
```

Pero cómo podría llenar el siguiente dropdownlist en cuanto se seleccione el primer valor?

Comment: con  un post desde ajax    quizá [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21472/filtrar-un-dropdownlist-desde-otro-dropdownlist)   pregunta puede ayudarte

Comment: Sii muchas gracias! Ya pude resolverlo

Comment: Dinos como lo resolviste.

Comment: Usé el mismo método que comentaron en la respuesta de abajo, un post desde ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente con JQuery una Peticion Ajax

@id = "ddl_CSN" le Agregas el ID a tu Dropdownlist en el HTML

y capturas el evento change en tu Control de la Siguiente Manera

```
@*<script>
    $("#ddl_CSN").on("change", function () {
        var valor = $("#ddl_CSN").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tu URL para Obtener los datos ",
            data: '{NameCS:"' + valor + '"}',
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (ent) {
                //alert(msg.nameConneccionS);
                los datos recuperados los asignas a tu siguiente control
            },
            error: function (ent) {
                console.log(ent.statusText);
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, así es como pude resolverlo

Comment: Excelente Erick .. cualquier duda contactame !!