# Como hacer un dropdownlist en cascada ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc

tengo el siguiente código, necesito que según la marca seleccionada me muestra la clase, ayudaaaa es urgente.
CONTROLLER

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        //Marca
        Task < ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TiposReferencia> TareaMarca = obj2.ObtenerVehiculoMarcaAsync("", ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoVehiculo.Auto);
        TareaMarca.Wait();
        if (TareaCiudad.Result.DescripcionError != "")
            MostrarError("Marca", TareaMarca.Result.DescripcionError);
        else
            ViewBag.MostrarMarca = LlenarcomboReferencia<ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoReferencia>((TareaMarca.Result.ListaTipoReferencia.ToList<ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoReferencia>()));

        //Clase
        Task<ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TiposReferencia> TareaClase = obj2.ObtenerVehiculoClaseAsync("", ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoVehiculo.Auto, ResultMarca);
        TareaClase.Wait();
        if (TareaCiudad.Result.DescripcionError != "")
            MostrarError("Clase", TareaClase.Result.DescripcionError);
        else
            ViewBag.MostrarClase = LlenarcomboReferencia<ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoReferencia>((TareaClase.Result.ListaTipoReferencia.ToList<ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoReferencia>()));
  return vew()}
```

View
      
            
                Marca

```
                @Html.DropDownList("MostrarMarca", null, "--Seleccione marca--", new { @class = "form-control", @onChange = "imprimirValor();" })

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Clase</label>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("MostrarClase", null,"--Seleccione Clase--", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

en este javascript tomo el dato

```
    function imprimirValor() {
        /* Para obtener el valor */
        var cod = document.getElementById("MostrarMarca").value;
        alert(cod)
    }
```

Comment: estoy utilizando un web services para los datos

Comment: Podrías hacerlo  con un change en el Drop de `MostrarMarca` y cada que se cambie con ajax mandas el valor a un método y que ese mismo regrese  los valores filtrados por el valor del Drop que previamente tomaste y pintarlos  en el succes de ajax en la etiqueta de tu segundo drop

Comment: puedes revisar  [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21543/10903) respuesra para darte una idea