# ¿Como puedo pasar el id a un metodo en una vista?

Tags: asp.net

Buenas gente estoy intentando pasar el valor del id dropDownList nombre a un método dentro de otro dropDownList(Unidad Medida) pero no entiendo como pasarlo para que lo tome y me muestre los datos, esto al momento de seleccionar el item de nombre

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nombre</label>                                            
    @Html.DropDownList("Nombre", Model.CargaItem(), new { @class = "form-control", 
    maxlength = "100", id = "drpItem" })                                                  
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Nombre")
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Unidad Medida</label>                                                
    @Html.DropDownList("UnidadMedida", Model.UnidadMedida(+idDropNombre), new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100" })                                                        
    @Html.ValidationMessage("UnidadMedida")
  </div>
```

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21472/822 + https://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/11/24/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cascading-dropdownlist-en-aspnet-mvc + https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+cascada + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: primero que nada, te faltan dos tags `</div>`